# using MongoDB in WSO2 EI

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to use MongoDB for the DBlookup in sequence. My WSO2 EI version 6.1.1. I using PostgreSQL to logging calling sequences steps. Is WSO2 supporting NoSQL(not RDBMS)? 
Here example my PostgreSQL DB lookup:

```
<dblookup>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <dsName>jdbc/WSO2EsbLogsDB</dsName>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[select id as table_name]]></sql>
        <result column="id" name="Id"/>
    </statement>
</dblookup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use a NOSQL database with a DBLookup mediator in WSO2 EI. The implementation does not support that.